# How to specify exact docker container version

Tags: docker

My server is having some weird bug I cannot find so I just deleted all docker images and downloaded them again. Weirdly the same bug now also appears in the updated version of the server. My hunch is, that docker does not download the exact same images but rather some updated versions which cause this bug.

Question is, how do I force docker to use the exact same versions as before?

Looking at my docker-compose.yml I can see that rabbitmq and mongo have differen "created" dates although their version number is specified in the docker-compose file:

```
services:
  messageq:
    image: rabbitmq:3
    container_name: annotator_message_q
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=user
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=password
    networks:
      - cocoannotator
  database:
    image: mongo:4.0
    container_name: annotator_mongodb
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/data/db
      - MONGO_LOG_DIR=/dev/null
    volumes:
      - "mongodb_data:/data/db"
    command: "mongod --smallfiles --logpath=/dev/null"
```

Is the specification rabbitmq:3 and mongo:4.0 not specific enough?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the bug? If you don't need the existing database data and the environment is development try running `docker-compose down -v` and then rebuilding the services with `docker-compose up -d --build`. This might fix the issue, but there is no way of saying for sure unless you provide more description on the bug. Warning `docker-compose down -v` will remove all the existing volumes you are using for your services.

Comment: I had a "bug-free" version  running a few months ago, so I just tried to reinstall that version. As the bug now also shows up in that version my estimate is, that rabbitmq or mongo versions have secretly changed so I just want to make sure docker installs 100% the exact same version to get rid of the bug

Comment: Basically your `rabbitmq:3` is not using the `3` tag and is using the `latest` tag. Is that the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the specification rabbitmq:3 and mongo:4.0 not specific enough?

It is not. Tags are mutable in Docker Hub and in other docker registries by default. This means, that you may have unlimited number of actual images - all registered as rabbitmq:3.

Full proof specific version variant is to use sha256 digests. This is the only recommended way for live systems. I.e. instead of `rabbitmq:3`, use

```
rabbitmq:3@sha256:fddabeb47970c60912b70eba079aae96ae242fe3a12da3f086a1571e5e8c921d
```

Unfortunately for your case, if you have already deleted all your images, you may not be able to recover what was the exact version. If you still have them somewhere, then do something like `docker images | grep rabbitmq` and then `docker image inspect` on matching images to find out their sha256 digests.